# Proof verification of von Neumann's ergodic theorem by spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, ergodic-theory

I would like to make sure the following proof is correct.

Spectral theorem, simplest form I will be using-

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T:H \to H$ normal, then we may wlog assume  $H = L^2 (X,u)$ where $X$ is a second countable locally compact Hausdorff (these properties are easy since $X$ will be a countable union of compact subsets of $C$), and $u$ is a complete probability regular measure (the Riesz-Markov gives that it's complete so let's take that for fun), and $T$ acts by $M_f$.

Von Neumann's ergodic theorem-

Suppose $T : L^2 (Y,v) \to L^2 (Y,v)$ is unitary, let $U$ denote the closed fixed subspace of $T$, and $P_U$ the projection. Then for any $h \in L^2(Y,v)$,

$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n T^i(h) \to P_U(h)$.

**Proof**-

Since unitary is normal, we use the spectral theorem to transfer our world to that of $H=L^2(X,u)$, $T = M_f$.

Since $T$ is unitary, the spectrum lies in $S^1$ (this is because it is contained in the disk of radius $1$, and $T^*(T-r) = 1-rT^*$, and the right is invertible when $|r|<1$ by the geometric series). This lets us assume wlog that $f$ takes only values on $S^1$ (because where it doesn't, is of measure $0$, since the support of the pushforward of the measure to $\mathbb{C}$ is the spectrum).

Now, $U$ is identified as the functions with a representative supported in $f=1$, and multiplying by the indicator of $f=1$ is thus the projection.

Now for any fixed function $g \in L^2 (X,u)$
$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f^ig \to P_U(g)$ pointwise, by DCT (dominated by max($10g^2,10)$) this gives the desired convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the Spectral Theorem ensures that $X$ has finite measure, your argument looks good to me.

Comment: I believe we can assume finite measure (since everything is countable, in the proof of the spectral theorem when you divide your hlibert space to an orthogonal sum of cyclic ones, and on each put a spectral measure, normalize the ith one to have total measure $1/2^i$

Comment: The cyclic subspaces won't necessarily be supported on finite measure spaces however. At any rate, any change in measure would change the definition of $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: I think they will, the total measure corresponding to a cyclic generated by $v$ is $||v||^2$ (i.e <$1\cdot v, v>$). I don't understand your second sentence, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: If you change the measure on a measure space, the space of $L^2$ functions on that measure space will change, as will the notion of $L^2$ convergence. In other words, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the $L^2$ sense in the first measure, you might not have $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the $L^2$ sense with the second measure.

Comment: I should have stated the spectral theorem more clearly, but the point is that they're isomorphic as hilbert spaces, so convergence in one translates to convergence in the other.

Comment: If you can assume $X$ has measure $1$ in the spectral theorem then you're fine. (I don't know the most general statement that applies here.)

Comment: I hunted around on the internet.. it seems like the measure $1$ condition holds when the Hilbert space is separable, but the mean ergodic theorem holds even in the nonseparable case. But as long as you restrict to the separable case your argument should be ok. Interestingly I also read that Von Neumann's original proof used the spectral theorem on unitary operators.

Comment: There is a trick that lets you assume this. First, use the spectral theorem for nonseparable. Now given Mf,g, consider the subsigma algebra they generate. Now move to it and start over

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. Actually, I think that just restricting attention to the $L^2$-closure of the functions $T^ih$ (which is a separable Hilbert space) should suffice.